# Записать в БД форму с неизвестным количеством полей

Tags: php, база-данных, форма

Подскажите, пожалуйста, новичку самый простой способ решения такой задачи:

Есть html-форма, в которую динамически на jquery добавляются поля с классом userdata с данными. Этих input class="userdata" может быть добавлено от 0 до нескольких десятков. Вот так добавляю (последний инпут - результат):

```
$('checkbox').click(function() {
$("form").append("input.userdata);   }); // добавляем инпут к существующей форме из 3 полей:
    <form id = "add_field_area">
        <input id = "fio">
        <input id = "phone">
        <textarea id = "message">
        <input class="userdata">
```

Мне нужно записать в БД данные этой формы.

ВОПРОС: как записать все данные ДОБАВЛЕННЫХ юзером полей в таблицу user_data независимо от их количества?

То есть задача в том, как записать в таблицу user_data неизвестное заранее количество инпутов с классом userdata.

Буду благодарна за пример кода. 
Спасибо!

Comment: Сводите все input в одну строку с разделителями и записывайте в одно поле бд.

Comment: В чем именно вы видите проблему?

Comment: В неизвестном количестве полей формы, которые нужно записать в одно поле БД. Coder подсказал, как это можно сделать.

Answer (score 1):

```
$DB -> Query( "INSERT INTO user_data(ID, VAL) VALUES (1, '". serialize($_POST) ."')" );
```

или

```
foreach($_POST as $k => $v){ 
    $DB -> Query( "INSERT INTO user_data(KEY, VAL) VALUES ($k, $v)" );
}
```